# problema ao executar o ng serve no angular

Tags: angular

Eu apaguei oq tinha no app.componente.html e depois usei o angular cli e botei as tags dos novos componentes no app.componente.html, mas o chat gpt diz que tenho q configurar o app.module, porem acho que essa versao nao tem esse componente module, aqui a msg de erro:

ng serve
Application bundle generation failed. [11.558 seconds]
✘ [ERROR] NG8001: 'app-menu-bar' is not a known element:

1. If 'app-menu-bar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is included in the '@Component.imports' of this component.
2. If 'app-menu-bar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@Component.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

   src/app/app.component.html:3:0:
   3 │ 
   ╵ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

```
src/app/app.component.ts:8:15:
  8 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

✘ [ERROR] NG8001: 'app-menu-title' is not a known element:

1. If 'app-menu-title' is an Angular component, then verify that it is included in the '@Component.imports' of this component.
2. If 'app-menu-title' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@Component.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

   src/app/app.component.html:4:0:
   4 │ 
   ╵ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

```
src/app/app.component.ts:8:15:
  8 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Watch mode enabled. Watching for file changes...

Comment: Observe que todo o projeto angular tem um app.module, onde são declaradas as dependências do projeto.
Verifique seu componente angular "app-menu-bar"